# How to get ID of input-feature of Oriented minimum bounding box (OMMB)

Tags: qgis

I'd like to get the OMMB of a number of input-features by qgis-processing-tool "ommb" in qgis 2.18.11.
I'd like to join the attributes of the resulting (ommb)-layer to the input-features. But the layer only contains the fields "area", "perimeter", "angle", "with" and "height" - but no key-field to the input-features (unlike to similar functions in ArcGIS).
Can anybody tell me how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Use the **Join attributes by location** tool and set the `Geometric predicate` option to _intersects_ and the `Joined table` option to _Keep all records_ :)

Comment: There are a lot of overlapping ommb-polygons in the dataset. The spatial-join-function will have the problem to select the correct ommb-polygon. The  problem is in both join directions input<->ommb